# Flutter click on the whole map Widget

Tags: flutter

I have a map view (Google Map: https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter) in flutter. I don't want to handle onTouch and Markers. I want to create a touch/click listener to the whole map widget. Any way to do it?

Comment: outer `GestureDetector` does not work?

Comment: No it not works

Comment: ok so `GoogleMap` has also `onTap` or `onLongPress`  properties, did you try it?

Comment: @pskink this is!!! onTap do the magic

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your Map widget with `AbsorbPointer`. This will prevent Map widget from getting the touch/click/tap events.

Now wrap the `AbsorbPointer` with a `GestureDetector` and handle `onTap` or whatever other gestures you want to handle.

This will allow only touch/click/taps on the `AbsorbPointer` widget, not on the map widget.

Let me know if any doubts.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your Widget with a `GestureDetector` and set `behaviour: HitTestBehavior.opaque`.
This will not allow the hits to be registered by the child.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the child by `InkWell` and give the `onTap()` event to it